# jQuery - JsTree checkbox select different

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I've got a JsTree with checkboxes in my program like this: [image]

By default, if I check a folder like '2' JsTree check also all her child but I need to allow to select a folder with or without her child.
At the end the options will be:

> 1. Select folder '2' whit all her child
> 2. Select only a child of folder '2' (whitout folder '2')
> 3. Select only folder '2'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `three_state: false` to your jsTree config:

```
$('#...').jstree({ 
    core : {
      data : ...
    },
    plugins : [ "checkbox" ],
    checkbox: {
        three_state: false
    }
});
```